# Nested If loops that delete sheets in excel vba dont do their assigned function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code that i do not seem to be able to fix. Essentially what I Am trying to do is to have 2 nested if conditions. One of them checks if the name of the sheet starts with "properties_auto" to avoid deleting sheets that have nothing to do with them. The second one checks if the name includes either one of two "deposits" that i am using. If the first condition is met but the second one isn't then the sheet is deleted,to avoid having useless sheets. 
The problem here is that the code seems to delete all of the sheets that include properties_auto in their code.

Here is the code:

```
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim count_heat As Integer
count_heat = 0

For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    count_heat = 0
    For i = 1 To deposits.count
        If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name),UCase("Properties_auto")) Then
            If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name),UCase(deposits(i))) Then
            Else
                count_heat = count_heat + 1
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next i
    If count_heat > 0 Then
        oSheet.Delete
    Else
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @R-de-Rojas: what is the value of  `deposits(i)` in your immediate window inside the loop? in the VBE, strike CTRL+G, and add `?deposits(i)` ... on the line `If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name),UCase(deposits(i))) Then` put a breakpoint with F9 and re-run your macro to compare the values in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing every element in the deposits array to the worksheet name. Even if one or two match, there must be others that do not and that increments count_heat  above zero.

Change the conditions of the value of count_heat.

```
If count_heat = deposits.count Then 'there were no matches at all
    oSheet.Delete
End If
```

You could also save some loops by exiting the For ... Next loop as soon as a match to one of the deposits was found. Note that this must still be used in concert with the If statement adjustment above.

```
If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name),UCase(deposits(i))) Then
    exit for
Else
    count_heat = count_heat + 1
End If
```

Comment: The line If count_heat > ubound(deposits) gives me type mismatch error. For clarification deposits is a range of size 2 currently

Comment: I thought it was an array. I'll make the adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I simplified the code somewhat:

```
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For i = 1 To deposits.Count
            If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name), UCase("Properties_auto")) Then
                If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name), UCase(deposits(i))) = 0 Then
                        oSheet.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next oSheet
```